# Adding custom Claim for access in API with IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm trying to work with a application to use IdentityServer4, it has the basic setup of the identity server, MVC client, and web API.

I have a custom Profile service (which I've registered in Startup.cs) where I'm adding a custom claim, here's my `GetProfileDataAsync` method:

```
public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject).Result;

    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim("TestFullName", user.FullName),
    };

    context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);          

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

My problem is that when I log into the identity server, I can see the additional claim - but when I call my API from the MVC app, my custom claim isn't there. Here's the code in my MVC app to call the API:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ClientAuthorizedAPICall(string token)
{
    // discover endpoints from metadata
    var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");

    // request token
    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");
    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("testAPI");        

    // call api
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");
    ...
}
```

And the method on my API is simply:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });           
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I be doing something different instead of using `User.Claims`?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `GetProfileDataAsync()` does it get called?

Comment: @Peter - yes it does, and the claims are added when I login

Comment: So you're logging in to your MVC app (via IdentityServer) and your user in the MVC app has the claim and that all works correctly. But then it looks like you have an action in that MVC app that uses client credentials to get an access token to call an API endpoint ... and you're wondering why the claim is not available in the API?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: You need to send the access token received from identity server when the user is signed into MVC app. The access token received from client credential flow has no way of knowing who the user is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like rawel's comment says, you'll want to use the MVC app user's access token to make your API call. It would look something like this:

```
// get the current user's access token
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

// call api
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");
```

You can see a similar approach in the [quickstart on hybrid flow](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html).

To get your custom user claim into the access token for your API, you'll need to include it when defining the API resource. For example:

```
new ApiResource("testAPI", "Test API", new[] { "TestFullName" }),
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter, that did work. I'm not sure why, but using your method to get the access token worked, but mine didn't, even though they both give me the same access token. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: That's strange - I wouldn't expect the client credentials access token to be the same as the user's access token. The client credentials token should not contain any user/identity claims.

Comment: So how would you add custom claims to the token?